# Flutter firestore QuerySnapshot has no instance of getter 'documents' in Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the values of the variables from the firestore cloud. Through implementing the code, I've seemed to come across an error, and I've spent hours getting frustrated over this, trying to find solutions here and elsewhere. The error I've faced alongside the code is as per below.

*The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:_StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#4939b):
**Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: documents***

[Error Displayed on the Virtual Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGF1J.png)

Code that I am using:

```
 Widget buildStreamBuilder() {
     return Container(
        child: !_success
            ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
          ),
        )
            : StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sensors').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
                if (doc.documentID == 'cSBKpiEe1XKmQC8BDzMk') {
                  print('current value = ${doc['BatStat']}'); //var1
                  globalCurrentSensorValue = doc['BatStat'].toDouble();
                }
              });
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
```

Comment: As Peter answered: the property was renamed from `documents` to `docs`. I recommend keeping the [reference docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) open, as they make it much easier to solve this type of problem on your own. It was also mentioned in the [migration guide](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html): "DEPRECATED: `documents` has been deprecated in favor of `docs`"

Comment: Hi ZenithAoa and welcome to StackOverFlow. Your question looks really good and well formatted. Only one tidbit regarding the screenshot. External links can be ephemeral so it would be nice if you could display the picture straight in the question. Good job.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for the information. As I'm new to the Flutter/Dart environment it was quite a stretch for me. Never knew the reference documentation was so helpful, was able to allow me to resolve a few issues within a few minutes after the stated one above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc)
```

into this:

```
snapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc)
```

`QuerySnapshot` class contains a property called `docs` which will return all the documents in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong you are accessing the document data incorrectly.
try this:

```
 if (doc.documentID == 'cSBKpiEe1XKmQC8BDzMk') {
              //use doc.data()[' '] method
              print('current value = ${doc.data()['BatStat']}'); //var1
              globalCurrentSensorValue = doc.data()['BatStat'].toDouble();
            }
```